# Set 'Copy Data' source folder with @item().name in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, dynamic-content

I have the following pipeline:
[image]

Get Metadata1 basically retrieves child items (which is collection of folders i.e. `originalFolder1`, `originalFolder2`, etc..).

Inside ForEach1 activity, I put copy data activity.

When defining the source dataset, I would like to use the retrieved folder name as the path. So It would be like this: `staticFolder1/staticFolder2/originalFolder1`.

I did try using `staticFolder1/staticFolder2/@item().name` in the folder path but it always throw an error `file not found`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where did you copy it from, is it a storage account?

Comment: @BowmanZhu both source and sink are from DataLake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, in ADF you can't mix string and expression, you can only have one or the other

what you can do is:

```
@concat(variables('SourceFolderName'), '/', string(item().name) )
```

say if you have a variable called SourceFolderName, which can be useful if your source folder is different everyday; otherwise make it as a string

```
@concat('staticFolder1/staticFolder2/', string(item().name) )
```

then you can concatenate the ForEach activity's item to form the complete path

Answer (score 0):

The comments provided by @sowmen makes sense, but it's not necessary to convert the item().name to string format.

There is an other interesting concept called String Interpolation, which makes our life more easier. Please see below the code that fits your scenario. Hope it helps :)

```
staticFolder1/staticFolder2/@{item().name}
```